# CORS not image-enabled. What to do?

Tags: flutter, cors

In the two examples below, the first returns the image correctly, in the second it gives an error:

> "Failed to load network image".

Is this a CORS issue? That is, on the server in the second example, cross-origin is not enabled? What to do?

```dart
Image.network('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/12/06/11/03/brazil-3001462_960_720.png')
```

```dart
Image.network('https://www.camara.leg.br/internet/deputado/bandep/204379.jpg')
```

Thank you very much

Comment: are you running on web?

Comment: I'm using chrome (web-javascript) as emulator

Comment: Yes. Solved. Thank you very much
God bless you.

Comment: Glad to help you out, feel free to close the question by  accepting duplication.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `html` renderer to overcome the issue, `c`is here for chrome.

```
flutter run -d c --web-renderer html
```